# Cats semigroup to merge List of HashMaps into One Scala

Tags: merge, hashmap, scala-cats, semigroup

I have a list of hashMaps as follows :

```
val listHashMaps = List(Map(1 -> List("one", "A") , Map(2 -> List("two", "B"), Map(3 -> List("three", "C"), Map(4 -> List("four", "D")
```

I want to merge these HashMaps into a single HashMap as :

```
 Map(1 -> List("one", "A"), 2 -> List("two", "B"), 3 -> List("three", "C", 4 -> List("four", "D")
```

I have tried

listHashMaps.flatten.ToHashMap 
but it does not seem to work. and I've read that it is possible to do it using semigroups from cats
as follows but I can seem to figure out how to iterate over the List in order to merge the HashMaps into a single one.

```
val combinedMap = Semigroup[HashMap[Int, List[String]]].combine(aMap, anotherMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use a `NonEmptyList` and then the default semigroup (which will just concatenate the maps), or you can use the unsafe `.reduce` function on `List`.

The reason it's unsafe is that it'll blow up on an empty list. Example:

```scala
import cats.data.NonEmptyList

import scala.collection.immutable
import cats.implicits._

object Foo extends App {

  val listHashMaps: List[Map[Int, List[String]]] = List(
    Map(1 -> List("one", "A")),
    Map(2 -> List("two", "B")),
    Map(3 -> List("three", "C")),
    Map(4 -> List("four", "D"))
  )

  val one: Map[Int, List[String]] = listHashMaps.reduce(_ ++ _)

  // safe
  val nonEmpty: NonEmptyList[Map[Int, List[String]]] = NonEmptyList.of(
    Map(1 -> List("one", "A")),
    Map(2 -> List("two", "B")),
    Map(3 -> List("three", "C")),
    Map(4 -> List("four", "D"))
  )

  val two: Map[Int, List[String]] = nonEmpty.reduce

  println(one)
  println(two)
}
```